# Checking client exceptions in DLQ messages

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

Right now I'm working with a JMS queue that has a redelivery policy such that messages that are rolled back more than five times are sent to a dead letter queue.

When a message is sent to a Dead Letter Queue in ActiveMQ, is there a way to see what exception caused that message rollback?  Is there a message property I can set to specify what caused the message failure?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the dead letter channel functionality
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html
of the AMQ broker then its as answered above, literally just the message that couldn't be delivered. The broker does not have any knowledge what went wrong, it just gets a 'rollback' signal on the message.

If you use Camel's dead letter channel functionality
http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html
then Camel stores the caused exception as a property on the Exchange, which you can enrich on the failed message, and send it to a dead letter queue, in the AMQ broker. So instead of letting AMQ rollback the message, you handle the exception, and send the message to another queue, which happens to be a dead letter queue. You can then enrich the message by taking the stacktrace and/or exception message from the Exchange property and store somewhere on the message, in a header etc.

Camel stores the caught exception as a property on the Exchange with the key: Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT

Comment: Oh and there is also an option named: useOriginalMessage which you may want to google on the Camel site to see what it does, if using the Camel dead letter channel functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look in the logs on the box that's generating the exception. What's sent to the DLQ is literally just the message that couldn't be delivered.

Comment: Yes if its the AMQ broker which performs the move the message to the DLQ, then the broker have no knowledge of any stacktraces occurred on the client etc.